# How to find the accurate device country name globally without asking user permission in android?

Tags: android, location

1. As many of the targeted devices don't have calling facility we
   cannot depend on service provider.
2. We cannot use `googleapis`, because the service is not available in
   China.

Comment: You can use the locale of the device anytime.

Comment: @Prashant Sable : It is not accurate

Answer (score 1):

You can use GPS/Network location service in any country. then upload user location to your server and **it can identify user country by latitude and latitude**

```
LocationListener locationListener = new LocationListener() {


        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status,
                                    Bundle extras) {

        }


        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

        }


        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {

        }


        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            if (location != null) {

                longitude = location.getLongitude();
                latitude = location.getLatitude();
            }
        }
    };

    try {
        Location location = null;

        LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

        if (locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)) {
            location = locationManager
                    .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

        } else if (locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER)) {
            location = locationManager
                    .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
        }
        if (locationManager.getAllProviders().contains(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER)) {
            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 1000, 0, locationListener);
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: But you should tell user you upload user location to server.